# Primary key for MySQL high score table using Facebook, Google Play or Game Center id?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a high score table which currently uses facebook login to record the users high scores.

However I am aware that not everyone would want to use facebook just to store a high score, and in fact many people are immediately put off by facebook login.

So my idea is to use their Google Play id on android devices, and their Game Center id on iOs devices.

My problem is that I would ideally like a user to be able to unify their games across the 2 platforms. This is the only reason I plan to keep facebook login in the game, as the ID number from that is not dependent on the platform.

E.g. 
User plays on their iPhone, I retrieve their GC id and use that to populate a "profile_id" primary key in the mysql table. 
They then log in using facebook. Would it be best to create a new row with the facebook ID as the "profile_id", and then put the previous profile_id into an "apple_id" column?
This way, if they then log in on an Android phone using facebook, I can retrieve the game data from their iOS session.

It seems to me like there is probably a fairly simple solution to this, but I'm stuck in one of those loops where you think about doing it one way and then realize you've already tried that before.

Does anyone have any good ideas on how they would do this?

Edit: I should add that one of the areas I'm getting a brainfreeze thinking about is this. Let's say I have a facebook id and an apple id stored for the user. If the next time they update the score they are not logged into facebook and so only the apple id is sent as part of the query, how can I make sure I don't replace the facebook id field with null or ""?

I could do :

```
if ($facebookID != "" && $facebookID != NULL)
{
$sql = "UPDATE scores SET facebook_id = '$facebookID' WHERE profile_id = $profile_id;";

}

if ($appleID != "" && $appleID != NULL)
{
$sql = "UPDATE scores SET apple_id = '$appleID' WHERE profile_id = $profile_id;";

}

if ($googleID != "" && $googleID != NULL)
{
$sql = "UPDATE scores SET google_id = '$googleID' WHERE profile_id = $profile_id;";

}
```

But that seems like it's not very efficient. Is there a way to only update a field if the variable is not null/blank?

Comment: What you are trying to do is use what is called a "Natural Key" as your primary key for users, yet your "Natural Key" spans different systems, which have to be handled differently in code.  That's why it seems so hacky and unscalable.  Please consider using an Identity field for your user, and keep the credentials separate from your unique identifier.

Comment: Is this great advice? I'm not convinced.

Comment: @Strawberry : Do you think having 3 hard coded checks everywhere you would need a single check in your code logic is a better idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of unique users and login credentials should be seperate.  You need a Guid or Int or BigInt primary key on a users table that represents a unique user.  Then it doesn't matter what credentials they use.  If the amount of "login" credentials you need to add is going to be fairly static, you can get away with adding them as columns in the same table.  If you want it to be dynamic, you need another table where each row is something like UserId (fk to user table), LoginType(1=facebook, etc), Username, PasswordHash, then by adding new LoginTypes you can add login logic for new authentication provider fairly easily.  You can then retrieve a user and his/her login information with a single table join.

Again, i am not sure exactly what you need, but my interpretation would look something like this...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [UserId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [Enabled] bit NOT NULL)

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfiles](
    [UserId] [bigint],  -- Combined Key (UserId, and ProfileServiceId)
    [ProfileServiceId] [nvarchar] (150),
    [ProfileType] [int] NOT NULL, -- 1 = Facebook, 2 = Google, etc..    
    [Enabled] bit NOT NULL)

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserScores](
    [UserScoreId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [bigint],
    [ProfileServiceId] [nvarchar] (150),
    [ScoreValue] [int] NOT NULL

    -- Get all Facebook scores for current user
    select * from UserScores where UserId = $currentUser.UserId and ProfileServiceId = $currentUser.FacebookProfileId

    -- Get all scores for current user 
    select * from UserScores where UserId = $currentUser.UserId

    -- Get all profiles for current user
    select * from UserProfiles where UserId = $currentUser.UserId

    -- See if user has a facebook profile
    select * from UserProfiles where UserId = $currentUser.UserId and ProfileType = $ProfileTypes.Facebook
```

Comment: So are you saying I could for example:
Create a unique user by just using auto-increment. Then store whichever values I have received from the facebookid, appleid and googleid. Then when they next login just check which ones I have received in the query, and use that to determine what to do next (i.e UPDATE highscores SET points = $points WHERE facebook = facebookid OR apple = appleid OR google = googleid)?

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on how you track your "score", but really you should be applying the score against the UserId which is unique to a user, regardless of his service id's.  UPDATE highscores SET points = $points where UserId = $currentUser->Id

Comment: Then when you need to pull scores you can just look at the scores table, if you need a facebook id from a high scoring user you could do, SELECT * from UserCredentials where UserId = $highScoreUser and LoginType = 1, assuming LoginType 1 is a lookup for Facebook, or 2 if you need google, 3 if you need apple, etc...